# Searching by multiple fields across multiple collections in a single query in mongodb. [using aggregate & populate functions]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here, we've two mongo collections [Ad and Company]. A company can have multiple ads.

Need an API endpoint that should return the ads matching the keyword entered. Searching across the company name, primary text, headline, and description in a single query using aggregate & populate functions.

These are the schemas for both of them:

```
const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  url: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const Company = mongoose.model("company", CompanySchema);
```

```
const AdSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  primaryText: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  companyId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "company",
    required: true,
  },
  headline: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
    default: "",
  },
  CTA: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

AdSchema.index({ primaryText: 'text', headline: 'text', description: 'text' });
const Ad = mongoose.model("ad", AdSchema);
```

This is the approach I've taken but here I'm not able to search by company Name. Can anyone please help me in the matter, what is wrong with the below approach and what's the correct approach?

```
router.get("/search", async function (req, res, next) {
  const query = req.query.query;

  const ads = await Ad.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        $text: {
          $search: query,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "companies",
        localField: "companyId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "company",
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$company",
    },
  ]);
  res.json(ads);
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add company name into ad collection as well.

Comment: @YellowDigitalLabs No this needs to be separate, what if there are other fields [personal to compny] like URL, etc, that I want to search by also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your modified answer.

```
router.get("/search", async function (req, res, next) {
const query = req.query.query;
const ads = await Ad.aggregate([
{
  $match: {text:query},
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "companies",
    localField: "companyId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "company",
    },
},
{
   $unwind: "$company",
},
]);
  res.json(ads);
});
```

or

This will find your query any where within the text.

```
router.get("/search", async function (req, res, next) {
const query = req.query.query;
const ads = await Ad.aggregate([
{
  $match: {text:{
      $regex: `.*${query}.*`,
      $options: 'i'
    }
},
},
{
  $lookup: {
    from: "companies",
    localField: "companyId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    as: "company",
    },
},
{
   $unwind: "$company",
},
]);
  res.json(ads);
});
```